# ¿Cómo puedo validar un select dependiente de otro en Javascript?

Tags: javascript, select, validación

mi problema es el siguiente: Tengo 2 Select en un formulario, uno de ellos esta oculto y solo aparece al elegir una opción del otro select que esta visible. ¿Cómo puedo hacer para que sea obligatorio poner el valor del select oculto cuando es visible antes de enviar el formulario? puedo hacer que sea obligatorio el primer select pero el segundo no.. Agradezco sus respuestas.

Tengo un ejemplo sencillo de mi problema.

```js
var formulario = document.getElementById('formulario');
var selectPrincipal = document.getElementById('principal');
var selectSecundario = document.getElementById('secundario');

selectPrincipal.addEventListener('change', function(){
    if(selectPrincipal.value == 'si') {
        selectSecundario.disabled = false;
    } else {
        selectSecundario.disabled = true;
    }
});

formulario.addEventListener('submit', function(e){
    if(selectPrincipal.value != 0) { // Aqui deberia ir la validacion del segundo select pero no se como hacerla

        alert('formulario enviado');
    } else {
        alert('Por favor dinos si tienes mascota');
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

```html
<form action="#" id="formulario">
    <select name="principal" id="principal">
        <option value="0">¿Tienes mascota?</option>
        <option value="si">Si</option>
        <option value="no">No</option>
    </select>

    <select name="secundario" id="secundario" disabled>
        <option value="perro">Perro</option>
        <option value="gato">Gato</option>
        <option value="ave">Ave</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
</form>
```

Comment: Si ya lo tienes casi !!, piensa en pseudo codigo: Compruebo si tiene mascota ->si ¿ha elegido mascota? -> si puedes enviar

Comment: No entiendo bro, habría alguna manera de que me pudieras explicar con código por favor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Los campos de un formulario HTML tienen un atributo que te puede ser útil: `required`.

Para hacerlo funcionar en un select, la opción inicialmente seleccionada debe tener un valor nulo. Una vez que cumplimos este requisito, la validación se hace automáticamente. Por tanto, lo que podrías hacer es algo como:

```js
var formulario = document.getElementById('formulario');
var selectPrincipal = document.getElementById('principal');
var selectSecundario = document.getElementById('secundario');

selectPrincipal.addEventListener('change', function(){
    if(selectPrincipal.value == 'si') {
        selectSecundario.disabled = false;
        selectSecundario.required = true;
    } else {
        selectSecundario.disabled = true;
        selectSecundario.required = false;
    }
});

formulario.addEventListener('submit', function(e){
  alert('formulario enviado');
});
```

```html
<form action="#" id="formulario">
    <select name="principal" id="principal" required>
        <option value="">¿Tienes mascota?</option>
        <option value="si">Si</option>
        <option value="no">No</option>
    </select>

    <select name="secundario" id="secundario" disabled>
        <option value="">Selecciona una</option>
        <option value="perro">Perro</option>
        <option value="gato">Gato</option>
        <option value="ave">Ave</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
</form>
```

Como puedes ver, si el formulario no es válido, ni siquiera se lanza en evento submit. Si aun así quieres mostrar un alert, podríamos escuchar el evento del botón que genera el submit:

```js
const formulario = document.getElementById('formulario');
const selectPrincipal = document.getElementById('principal');
const selectSecundario = document.getElementById('secundario');
const boton = document.getElementById('btnSubmit');

selectPrincipal.addEventListener('change', function(){
    if(selectPrincipal.value == 'si') {
        selectSecundario.disabled = false;
        selectSecundario.required = true;
    } else {
        selectSecundario.disabled = true;
        selectSecundario.required = false;
    }
});

formulario.addEventListener('submit', function(e){
  alert('formulario enviado');
});

boton.addEventListener('click',() => {
  if (!formulario.checkValidity()) {
    alert('El formulario no es válido, no se hará submit');
  }
});
```

```html
<form action="#" id="formulario">
    <select name="principal" id="principal" required>
        <option value="">¿Tienes mascota?</option>
        <option value="si">Si</option>
        <option value="no">No</option>
    </select>

    <select name="secundario" id="secundario" disabled>
        <option value="">Selecciona una</option>
        <option value="perro">Perro</option>
        <option value="gato">Gato</option>
        <option value="ave">Ave</option>
    </select>
    <button type="submit" id="btnSubmit">Enviar"</button>
</form>
```